# Using super() to inherit from multiple Sessions in Python requests

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

In order to write many HTTP requests in a DRY way, I'd like to define several subclasses of [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) Sessions and inherit from them as needed. I've tried the following:

```
import requests, time

requestbin_URL = 'http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1'      # For testing only; remains usable for 48 hours
auth_token = 'asdlfjkwoieur182932385'               # Fake authorization token

class AuthorizedSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        super().__init__()
        self.auth_token = auth_token
        self.headers.update({'Authorization': 'token=' + self.auth_token})

class JSONSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.headers.update({'content-type': 'application/json'})

class DebugSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, verify=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.verify = verify

class AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession, DebugSession):
    def __init__(self, auth_token, verify=False):
        super().__init__(auth_token, verify=verify)

with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession() as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key" : "value"})
```

However, if I try to run this (in Python 3), I get

```
In [9]: exec(open('requestbin_test_python3.py').read())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cc670860ddd1> in <module>()
----> 1 exec(open('requestbin_test_python3.py').read())

<string> in <module>()

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'auth_token'
```

What I was hoping is that `super().__init__` as applied to `AuthorizedJSONDebugSession` would be 'clever enough' to understand that `auth_token` is to used to initialize `AuthorizedSession` and `verify` to initialize `DebugSession`. (A similar example using only `AuthorizedSession` and `JSONSession` did work).

However, this appears not to be the case. How can I modify this code to make it work?

Comment: You could use kwargs everywhere to give each superclass the parameter it actually needs, but I'd get rid of the multiple inheritance all together. It usually turns into a nasty source of bugs.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is tricky at best, and is better restricted to a "one base class + a couple mixins" use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of dealing with this is only allowing keyword parameters and make all classes accept `**kwargs`:

```
import requests, time

requestbin_URL = 'http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1'      # For testing only; remains usable for 48 hours
auth_token = 'asdlfjkwoieur182932385'               # Fake authorization token

class AuthorizedSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.auth_token = kwargs.pop('auth_token')
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError('Missing auth_token parameter!')

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.headers.update({'Authorization': 'token=' + self.auth_token})

class JSONSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.headers.update({'content-type': 'application/json'})

class DebugSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.verify = kwargs.pop('verify', False)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession, DebugSession):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession() as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key" : "value"})
```

The `dict.pop` method looks for the given key and removes it from the dictionary. The second argument is the default value to use, if not provided `KeyError` is raised.

Note that it is *essential* that whenever you define a `__init__` in a subclass you also call `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, even if you think that in that case it is not needed. Because adding a subclass into a hierarchy of classes with multiple ancestors can change the mro and by not doing this call you may end up with broken initialization.

Comment: To avoid the `Missing auth_token parameter` TypeError I had to initialize `AuthorizedJSONDebugSession` as `AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(auth_token=auth_token)`.

Comment: @KurtPeek Well, if you want to provide a default value you could also do: `self.auth_token = kwargs.pop('auth_token', auth_token)` so that it will take the value of the global variable if the parameter is not passed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in great doubt such approach will work in general case, but you can try to call required `__init__` methods explicitly:

```
import requests, time

requestbin_URL = 'http://requestb.in/1nsaz9y1'      # For testing only; remains usable for 48 hours
auth_token = 'asdlfjkwoieur182932385'               # Fake authorization token

class AuthorizedSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        super().__init__()
        self.auth_token = auth_token
        self.headers.update({'Authorization': 'token=' + self.auth_token})

class JSONSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.headers.update({'content-type': 'application/json'})

class DebugSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, verify=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.verify = verify

class AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession, DebugSession):
    def __init__(self, auth_token, verify=False):
        AuthorizedSession.__init__(self, auth_token)
        JSONSessions.__init__(self)
        DebugSession.__init__(self, verify=verify)

with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(auth_token) as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key" : "value"})
```

Comment: No a great idea IMHO. If you can't make `super` work in multiple inheritance it's usually a strong design smell.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Agreed

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

```
class AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(AuthorizedSession, JSONSession, DebugSession):
    def __init__(self, auth_token, verify=False):
        super().__init__(auth_token, verify=verify)

with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession() as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key" : "value"})
```

Your problem is `with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession()` You're not providing any arguments, yet the init method requires 1 argument of the auth token. `def __init__(self, auth_token, verify=False)`

This is basically the same thing as trying to do the following:

```
>>> x=10
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x + 1
...
>>> foo()
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

In the scope of the function, `x` is not the same as the global `x`

To fix this do:

```
with AuthorizedJSONDebugSession(auth_token) as s:
    response = s.post(requestbin_URL, data={"key" : "value"})
```

Alternatively, you *could* change the init method to do this, but I wouldn't recommend it.

`def __init__(self, auth_token=auth_token, verify=False)`

You should also be careful in how you're using `super()` to pass arguments. There are some other problems with your code in this respect. You must make sure every class in the MRO is cooperating with what you want to do and is passing arguments to the superclass.

You should also be familiar with how Python's `super` works, which is different from other languages.